# identifier D3DReadFileToBlob is undefined?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, blob, directx, directx-11

```
#include<D3Dcompiler.h>

void Init()
{
    D3DReadFileToBlob(L"", nullptr);
}
```

it gives `D3DReadFileToBlob is undefined` error, i don't think it is a [linking error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860543/calling-d3dreadfiletoblob-in-visual-studio-2012-causes-link-error) and i read [this](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/627240-question-about-d3dreadfiletoblob/4954397/) which i don't get what am i suppose to do (i think that might be the cause)

so what should i do to fix this?

Comment: `D3DReadFileToBlob is undefined` does sound like a link error.

Comment: yes indeed it was a link error @wohlstad

Comment: Missing `#include`s usually cause compilation error (not link). Since you didn't share your complete error message it's all guessing. Anyway it's good that you sorted it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that i was using both Windows Kits and Directx SDK at the same time and that caused [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860543/calling-d3dreadfiletoblob-in-visual-studio-2012-causes-link-error), Because i was watching old tutorials i didn't know that i really don't need Directx SDK and i could use Windows Kits which already has everything in it for development of directx 11.

Comment: You may find [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2021-edition/) and [this one](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/) informative as well.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)